# Can't set inner HTML for Tree Map on Google Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, treemap

I'm pulling in data from a Google Sheet to draw a TreeMap. When I reach a leaf node on the chart, I want to replace the node text with some other text. Not trying to replace the data, just show different text for the leaf node.

For some reason I'm able to change the textContent, but the browser starts to crash without throwing an error when I try to change the innerHTML:

```
  function changeText() {
  var selection = chart.getSelection();
  console.log(selection);
  var details = data.getValue(selection[0].row, 4);
  if (details != null){
  console.log("leaf node selected");

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(rect) {
    var y = rect.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('text');
    var currentText = y[0].textContent;
    console.log(currentText);
    //this is fine
    y[0].textContent = details;

    //this makes computer explode
    //y[0].innerHTML = "<b>hello!</b>"
  });
}
}
```

This is how I'm calling that function:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(changeText);
observer.observe(container, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});
```

And I have "allowHtml:true" set in my options:

```
        chart.draw(data, {
      minColor: '#0583F2',
      midColor: '#05F2DB',
      maxColor: '#FFE86D',
      height: '740',
      headerHeight: 18,
      fontColor: 'black',
      showScale: false,
      showTooltips: true,
      generateTooltip: showFullTooltip,
      maxDepth:1,
      maxPostDepth:2,
      textStyle:{ color: 'black',
            fontName: 'Arial',
            fontSize: 16,
            bold: true,
            },
      hintOpacity:0,
      useWeightedAverageForAggregation:false,
      allowHtml:true
    });
```

Comment: the chart is drawn using SVG, not HTML. this is why the `innerHTML` method does not work. if you want to make the text bold, set the `font-weight` attribute on the `<text>` element. the `allowHTML` is not an option for the `TreeMap`. and on charts where it is an option, it's only for the tooltip, not the chart itself.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I'm trying to do more HTML formatting than just bolding... trying to pull in paragraphs of text, hyperlinks, etc. So sounds like I should seek a different path forward. Thanks for your help